# MySQL(?) to SQLite

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlite

I want to add this into SQLite, but I can't get alter table to work with add foreign key.
It looks like this:

`create table Medlem

(Mnr integer not null,

Namn varchar(6),

Telefon varchar(10),

primary key (Mnr));`

create table Sektion
(Skod char(1) not null,
Namn varchar(14),
Ledare integer,
primary key (Skod));

create table Deltar
(Medlem integer not null,
Sektion char(1) not null,
primary key (Medlem, Sektion));

alter table Sektion
add foreign key (Ledare) references Medlem (Mnr);
alter table Deltar
add foreign key (Medlem) references Medlem (Mnr);
alter table Deltar
add foreign key (Sektion) references Sektion (Skod);

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: I get syntax error for "foreign".

Comment: Do you have foreign key support enabled? (see http://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html)

Comment: @Raad *A `CREATE TABLE` command operates the same whether or not foreign key constraints are enabled*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way to implement a foreign key constraint in SQL Lite is during `CREATE TABLE`:

```
CREATE TABLE track(
  trackid     INTEGER, 
  trackname   TEXT, 
  trackartist INTEGER,
  FOREIGN KEY(trackartist) REFERENCES artist(artistid)
);
```

> It is not possible to use the `ALTER TABLE ... ADD COLUMN` syntax to add a column that includes a `REFERENCES` clause, unless the default value of the new column is `NULL`. Attempting to do so returns an error.

[Documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html#fk_schemacommands)

Comment: Thank you, I think I got it now.